# Identifying and locating records for town in Westfalen?

Tags: germany, locating-records, north-rhine-westphalia

My great  grandfather was George Eichstedt born July 13, 1851 in Germany. I found out he had a lot of names so he was Gustav Adolph Emil Franz George Eichsteadt. His father was Ferdanaid Eichsteadt and wife was Lina. They lived in Westfalen, North Rhine-Westphalia, Deustschland. City Gardela u Kwidzyn. Where in Germany is this place? How do I find records for this location?

Comment: Judy, welcome. I've edited your question to be a better fit on this site, so that it attracts some good answers. What is the source of the town "Gardela u Kwidzyn"? Might you have meant Gardeja?

Comment: The place is not in North-Rhine Westphalia, but today’s Poland (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardeja). Please show us the document with this entry, so we help you sorting things out.

Answer (score 1):

Gardeja - all my ancestry records point to here. The furthest I have traced is Eduard and Julie Graustein, daughter Auguste Graustein, married to William Grunth (various spellings). Seems Auguste died in Berlin, as did her husband, William, however.

Any chance Eduard and Julie are buried in or near Gardeja? They apparently had a son, Max, who died at age 22, 20 Feb 1884. It would be nice to have a photo of their grave if someone in the area could locate the graves.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.